# How to set context variable of all Django generic views at once?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I will have standard class-based views for CRUD operations that inherit from various generic views like ListView, DetailView and so on. 
I will be setting all of their 
`context_object_name` 
attribute to the same value.

I was wondering if there is a way to do it more pythonic, to not repeat the operations many times in the code, but to be able to change that variable in one place if necessary?

ps. what comes to my mind is of course further inheritance, but maybe there is some more django-like way?

Comment: Inheritance is the way to go here, it's pretty simple to define a base class that sets a single value.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a mixin, instead of a middleware app:

```
class CommonContextMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(CommonContextMixin, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['foo'] = 'bar'
    
        return context
```

Then use that mixin in your views:

```
class MyView(CommonContextMixin, TemplateView):
    """ This view now has the foo variable as part of its context. """
```

Relevant Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/mixins/

Answer (score 0):

[Middleware can do the trick](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/#process-template-response)

```
class SetContextObjectNameMiddleware:

    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        if 'object' in response.context_data:
            response.context_data['foo'] = response.context_data['object']
        return response
```

Then add the middleware to your `settings.py`

It's not really setting the view's `context_object_name` but it achieves the same outcome.